# How to publish trunk and tags as subfolder in gh-pages?

Tags: git, github

On GitHub, I'm looking for a way to publish my trunk and the tags as folder in gh-pages.

It means having an architecture like this one:

- index.html

  - /0.1
  - /0.2
  - /0.3
  - *etc.*
  - /trunk

The `index.html` is a simple liste page that liste all folder. (it can be build manually).

How do you manage to get that or have you any recommendations ?

The purpose of this is to be able to see each milestone of the dev process of a website.It's easier for me to have all version available than having the stakeholders asking me to publish the version of two months ago because they want to see something on it.